# Laravel eloquent model set condition at belongsTo method

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model class ServiceAgentRel. Where agent_id belongs to user table. I am fetching all column with service_id 3.

```
 $agent_data = App\ServiceAgentRel::where(['service_id'=>3])->with('agent')->get();
```

Using this code I can get all services with service_id 3 But I need to set a condition on user table if user status (status corresponding to that agent_id) is inactive no row will be fetched.
My main requirement is, I have to set a condition on a relation function agent(). Also is there any way to check it from controller?[image]

```
class ServiceAgentRel extends Model {
    public function agent(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'agent_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I know it is possible to do this task by a simple join, but I want to know if it is possible by eloquent model function.
Thanks
enter image description here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for that you need to use whereHas,like that

```
$agent_data = App\ServiceAgentRel::where(['service_id'=>3])->with('agent')
->whereHas('agent',function($query) {
 $query->where('status', 'active');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works except if I don't use array in whereHas function
I am seeing this error: ****Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::whereHas() must be an instance of Closure, none given****
So I have used 
whereHas('agent', function($query) {
                                $query->where('status', 'active');
                            })
instead of array. And it's working. Thank you.

Comment: @murad you are right.If this answer works for you,please make this accepted that will helpful for others.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel thanks mate it worked perfectly. Where can i find in depth explanation of  all these cool eloquent queries?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do like this

```
$agent_data = App\ServiceAgentRel::where(['service_id'=>3])->first();

echo $agent_data->agent->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this statement:

```php
$agent_data = App\ServiceAgentRel::where(['service_id'=>3])
  ->with(['agent' => function($query) {
      $query->where('agent.status', 'active');
  }])->get();
```